# ASP.Net Core 2.2 Controller Login Redirect to another [Authorize]Controller Action with Access Token

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, access-token, response.redirect, jwt

My Login controller action needs to `Redirect(returnUrl);` to another Controller action which has `[Authorize]` attribute. Login controler action generates Access and Refresh Tokens. Currently I append the `returnUrl` with the access token as query string which is then picked up by `JwtBearerEvents.OnMessageReceived` and successfully redirected to another controller action. However, this exposes the security token string in the browser address bar. What's the best practices and how to securely achieve this?

Comment: Redirect is 301/302 with the Location header set to the URL the client should redirect , that seems query string is the option since  you can't set HTTP headers to add the token either . Do you only have JWT token authentication in your application ?

Comment: JWT and cookie.